# Can't scrape job type or salary from api?

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I am using Indeed's JobSearch API. I am able to pull my results by using 2 fields (Job name and Location). When the JSON comes in, I can get information from it such as: Name, location, date posted, snipped information, job title, etc).

My jobtype always returns undefined.

Here is my data scraping
var locale, country, salary, jobtype, limit = 10;

```
$('#getResults').click(function(){
    jobSearch($('#locale').val(), $('#job').val(), jobtype, country,0,limit);
});

var results = $('body').find('#pagination');

results.on('click', 'li', function (e){
var start = ($(this).text() - 1) * limit, end = start + limit;
    jobSearch($('#locale').val(), $('#job').val(), country, jobtype, start, end);    
});
function jobSearch(locale, data, country, jobtype, start, end){
    var searchData = data;
```

Here is my api call:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    data: $.extend({
        publisher: '7512241874751817', //pub #
        v: '2', // vers. 2
        format: 'json',
        q: data,
        l: locale,
        jt: jobtype,
        radius: 50,
        limit: limit,
        sort: 'date',
        highlight: 1, //no extra bolding
        filter: 1,
        latlong: 1,
        co: country, //defaults to USA
        userip: '',
        useragent: '',
    }, {
        start: start,
        end: end
    }),
    dataType: 'jsonp', //return json
    type: 'GET',
    timeout: 5000, //break search after 5s
    url: 'https://www.indeed.com/ads/apisearch'
})
```

Here is my **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/padogt5m/9/)**.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/padogt5m/10/

Comment: @Hackerman ugh. I'm stupid. I meant to type "Job Type" not title. sorry!

Comment: I checked the api response and there is no `job type` field in the json response

Comment: It would be under `jt`. since that's the apis param

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question itself. Do not just include one portion of the code and a link. For instance, in this question, the important part is where you're getting the data from the response, not how you're calling the API. That should be here on Stack Overflow. See [mcve].